Error of Length of Dynamic Field Exceeding Max Length with LlamaIndex and Milvus
I was trying to build a RAG with the combination of both Llamaindex and Milvus, and I was referring to the code from this Llamaindex document: https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/examples/node_postprocessor/MetadataReplacementDemo/
Based on the code above, I modified it to use mainly Milvus with my own data inserted. However, when I attempted to make the index, some of the nodes were giving errors, saying how the length of dynamic field exceeds max length.
I thought this was due to the fact that the nodes were too big, thus I tried to decrease their sizes but still got the same error.
I was wondering if there is something I can do on the Milvus end, for example increasing the max limit.
The error suggests 'Please reduce your prompt; or completion length.', but I am not sure how to do that.
Here is my code for reference:
from llama_index.core import VectorStoreIndex
from llama_index.vector_store.milvus import MilvusVectorStore
from llama_index.core import StorageContext
from pymilvus import MilvusClient

client = MilvusClient(
    uri = "http://localhost:19530"
)

if client.has_collection(collection_name = "SWR_collection_for_all_nodes")
    client.drop_collection(collection_name = "SWR_collection_for_all_nodes")

count = 0
fails = 0
successes = 0

for x in nodes:
    count += 1
    try:
        del vector_store, storage_context, sentence_index
    except:
        pass
    vector_store = MiluvsVectorStore(uri = "http://localhost:19530", collection_name = "SWR_collection_for_all_nodes", dim = 1536, overwrite = False)
    storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(vector_store = vector_store)

    try:
        sentence_index = VectorStoreIndex([x], storage_context = storage_context)
    exception Exception as e:
        print(f"failed to add node {count} to storage")
        print(e)
        fails += 1
        continue
    print(f"node {count} added to storage")
    successes += 1

print(f"Added {success} nodes to storage, failed to add {fails} nodes")



It seems like this error is due to Milvus storing non-defined values into a dynamic field as a JSON string. For example, if the collection has two fields, id and vector, and you insert a row like this:
collection.insert({"id": 1, "vector": [xxxx], "label": "kkk", "flag": 888})

, the key-value pairs of label and flag will be stored as a JSON string {"label": "kkk", "flag": 888} in the dynamic field. If the byte length of the JSON string exceeds a threshold, which has default value 65536, you will encounter this error. There is a hidden configuration to define the threshold in the milvus.yaml:
common:
  JSONMaxLength: 65536

Enlarging this value might resolve your issue, but it is not recommended to insert such large content into Milvus. Additionally, when you call collection.load(), query nodes will load the data of all fields into memory, including the dynamic field. Long-length strings will significantly increase memory usage, and if the RAM capacity is insufficient, it might fail to load and cannot perform any search/query.
